# How to filter a merged Landsats collection by cloud coverage in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat

I have a collection of all Landsat 4, 5, 7, and 8 imagery that has been modified for future processing.

```
  var mergedCollection = L457Renamed.merge(L8Renamed);
```

A property for each image is "CLOUD_COVER".

I would like to create a filter for this merged collection that will remove imagery above an adjustable cloud cover threshold.

something like:
        var collectionCloudiness = mergedCollection.select("CLOUD_Cover less than 10")

Additionally, how do I copy code from GEE so that it keeps its formatting and colors?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: These are the instructions to format your code in the questions or answers:
Create code fences by placing your code between sets of 3 backticks ` or use CTRL + K

```
like so
```
Create inline code spans by placing text between single backticks

`like so`
Add a preformatted block within a list with eight spaces

1. This is normal text
2. This is a list item
 
        Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
        Eight spaces will trigger the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply a filter to your collection:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02')

print('unfiltered size', collection.size())  

var filtered = collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER', 20))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b89f2c48afb18ff53a221828ca23a03
    print('filtered size', filtered.size())